# elinks http autentication

Tags: linux, unix, elinks

I'm trying to use linux elinks text browser to go to a website. This site requires http authentication. If I press escape it and hide the login prompt once and then If I try to go the particular website again it doesn't show the login prompt again. I try "flush all caches" But it doesn't work until I close my terminal and get a new one. Is there any other way to get over with this?

This should be a simple question. But I googled and couldn't find a answer.

Comment: Do you have a link to the website in question? I tried it on one of my own, and elinks handles it fine, displaying a dialogue box asking for user name and password as expected.

Comment: Thanks for your precious time. I tried with another website. It gives me the prompt. So I figured out the problem is another. I have modified the question. Please go through it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried this with links version 2.2 on Fedora 17. I went to a website that requires basic authentication, got the popup password dialog, hit escape, saw the error msg. I then hit Ctrl-R to reload the page and was presented with the username and password prompt again. So I hit 'g' and entered 'google.com', went to google. Then hit 'g' and went back to my password protected site, and I'm asked for the username and password again. So I can't reproduce this issue.

Comment: I'm using elinks 0.12pre5 on ubuntu 12.04. I followed your steps on elinks. It gives the login prompt when I press Ctrl+R but if I hit G and enter the URL for auth required website again it doesn't give prompt. But with links It just work fine. So I think it's a bug with elinks. BTW I wasn't aware that links support session and authentication. Thanks for your answer.